# while run the java file i am getting an error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNIExample.getVersion([B[I)I

Tags: java-native-interface

```
D:\JNIExample\JNIExample\JNIExample>java JNIExample
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNIExample.getVersion([B[I)I
at JNIExample.getVersion(Native Method)
at JNIExample.main(JNIExample.java:15)

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the dll/so library with the native code?
Typically done in the class needing it, like this:

```
 static {
    try {
      System.loadLibrary("jniexample");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

**Edit:** accidentally used the old load call in the first answer. you probably should use loadLibrary(). See [this article](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1549365534-The-difference-between-System-load-and-System-loadLibrary-in-Java) for a comparison

Comment: it shows      Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: JNIExample.dll

Comment: @Fredrik confused `load` with `loadLibrary`. The latter searches the `java.library.path`, the former wants a full absolute pathanem.

Comment: yes sorry, my bad. I copied and pasted from ancient code. fixing